# Actionscript 3.0 random teleportation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I'm using Flash and decided to make my animation into a game of a sort. So I started out coding and I'm pretty far into it. But I came across a small problem when I went pressed my chosen key and it did what i wanted, but randomly teleported to the characters original location.

```
//FRAME 1
stop();
//--Developer William Richmond

import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,moveClipdown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,moveClipup);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,moveClipright);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,moveClipleft);


//Attempting the border restriction code
function limitStageBorder(object:MovieClip) {
//1.
var objectHalfWidth:uint=object.width/2;
var objectHalfHeight:uint=object.height/2;

//2.
if (object.x+objectHalfWidth>stage.stageWidth) {
   object.x=stage.stageWidth-objectHalfWidth;
}
else if (object.x -  objectHalfWidth <0) {        
   object.x=0+objectHalfWidth;    
}     

//3.    
if (object.y-objectHalfHeight<0) {        
   object.y=0+objectHalfHeight;    
}    
else if (object.y + objectHalfHeight > stage.stageHeight) {
   object.y=stage.stageHeight-objectHalfHeight;
}
}
//down
function moveClipdown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
              {
                  if(event.keyCode == 83)
                  {
                      mcSquare1.y += 25
                  }
              }
//up
function moveClipup(event:KeyboardEvent):void
              {
                  if(event.keyCode == 32)
                  {
                      mcSquare1.y -= 10
                      mcSquare1.gotoAndPlay(20);
                  }
              }
            //right  
function moveClipright(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
                  if(event.keyCode == 68){
                      trace("I am running to the right");
                      mcSquare1.scaleX = 0.75;
                      mcSquare1.x += 20
                      gotoAndStop(10);
                  }
}

            //Left  
function moveClipleft(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
                  if(event.keyCode == 65)
                  {
                      trace("I am running to the left");
                      mcSquare1.scaleX = -0.75;
                      mcSquare1.x -= 20
                      gotoAndStop(10);
                  }
              }
```

FRAME 10

```
stop();
//--Developer William Richmond

import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,moveClipright10);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,moveClipleft10);

            //right  
function moveClipright10(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
                  if(event.keyCode != 68){
                      trace("I am standing");
                      mcSquare1.scaleX = 0.75;
                      mcSquare1.x += 20
                      gotoAndStop(1);
                  }
}

            //Left  
function moveClipleft10(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
                  if(event.keyCode != 65)
                  {
                      trace("I am standing");
                      mcSquare1.scaleX = -0.75;
                      mcSquare1.x -= 20
                      gotoAndStop(1);
                  }
              }
```

So if anyone could have a go at helping out, it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: If your object is present on stage at design time on either frame, it will be re-created at originating position. Probably this is what's causing "teleportation". Animations and coding don't like to share the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Coding directly in frame can create all sorts of issues, especially when you change frame. Looking at the code is not enough to say whats wrong, sinc ein timeline programming all sort of things can happen on stage. I strongly suggest you to use a base class and code in there. Or if you really need to code in timeline, put everything in a single frame.